# Mustache considers string as a list of characters

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am trying to show a description with a Mustache template only if the string is not empty :

```
{{#description}}
<li>
  <a>
    <p>Description</p>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
  </a>
</li>
{{/description}}
```

I tried the script in [trymustache](http://trymustache.com) and it rendered only one `li` tag. However, my app renders multiple`li` tag container the Description `p`, but without the `{{description}}` rendered.

My Json looks like

```
{
  ...
  "description":"example"
  ...
}
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: what is your input json object like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that instead of `{{#description}}...{{/description}}` what you want is `{{#if description}}...{{/if}}`

Comment: `#if` does not exist in Mustache. You might be confused with Handlebars

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of Mustache.js?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your template @ trymustache; as per your experience, it rendered as many li tags as my example data provided.

My example:
    {{#description}}
        <li>
            <a>
                <p>Description</p>
                <p>{{description}}</p>
            </a>
  </li>
  {{/description}}

Comment: My json is `{"description":"example"}`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, my code was working in try mustache, but not in my app. So I settled for a jQuery solution for now :

```
$('.place_info').find('p:nth-child(2)').each(function(i, p) { if($(p).html() == '') { $(p).closest('li').remove();}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put block elements inside inline elements.  An anchor tag shouldn't have paragraph tags inside of it. The reason for this, I think, is due to the need to allow browsers to recover from parsing bad HTML. Furthermore, `li` tags need to have a `ul` or `ol` tag (I think there may be other tags applicable but I forget them) as parents with no other siblings but `li` tags. I suspect bad HTML is the root of your issue.

Comment: You may be right about the `p` tag. But there is a `ul`, just not in the question. The thing is the markup works if I remove the `{{#description}}` (just show the description, even if empty).

Comment: It's a bit surprising, but the mustache docs don't seem to have a use case for what you're doing here, unless I'm missing it:  http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html